# WildFly: как с другого компа подключиться к приложению на моём компе?

Tags: java, wildfly

На моём компе к своему приложению я подключаюсь набирая в браузере localhost/... Как подключиться к серверу WildFly (к моему приложению) по сети с другого компьютера?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно "повесить" Wildfly на ip-адрес компьютера в локальной сети, например `192.168.0.2` либо на `0.0.0.0` и с другого компьютера заходить на http://192.168.0.2

Сервер необходимо запускать с ключом `-b=192.168.0.2`

[Вот ответ на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028988/how-to-change-the-ip-address-of-wildfly-server)